# Facebook C# SDK, facebook app on fanpage redirects out of tab after login

Tags: redirect, permissions, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-page

I am working with the Facebook c# SDK (5.x). I have an app that runs on the fanpage in a tab. so far so good. when I ask for permissions, and i allow them, the user gets redirected to the app, but outside of the fanpage or tab.

Is there a way to stay inside the fanpage tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this was to set the CancelUrlPath (in case user dont allow permission) and ReturnUrlPath(in case he does) to the page url/page and application url. Both attributes from CanvasAuthorizer object.

var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer();

auth.CancelUrlPath = "PAGEURL";

auth.ReturnUrlPath = "PAGEURL with active TAB";

auth.Authorize();

I guess this the solution for now, since c# sdk dont have a nice support for tab applications.
Hope this helps.